# set up php file to allow for cross domain calls

Tags: php, jquery, regex

i am working with a server that has a boat load of unique ids

so full urls are as follows

http://football.myfantasyleague.com/ all the way to ----> http://football99.myfantasyleague.com/

http://www.myfantasyleague.com/ all the way to ---->  http://www99.myfantasyleague.com/

i need to set permissions via php on a different server then the one shown above that will allow some ajax , jquery cross domain calls to the initial site that has all the multiple server ids

What would be a simple regex code to write to allow for the various servers and ids ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   SetEnvIf Origin "^(https?://(?:football|www)\d{1,2}\.myfantasyleague\.com/?)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$1
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
</IfModule>
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Alex , i think that should get it, but i accidentally put in the incorrect manner in which they list each server , i updated my post and hope you can regenerate one that matches my corrections. Thanks and apologies for screwing up initial post

Comment: that did it ;) ty very much for taking the time